# Observable.of is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having issue with importing `Observable.of` function in my project. My Intellij sees everything. In my code I have:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and in my code I use it like that:

```
return Observable.of(res);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout the latest docs if you're using rxjs6 on the correct import and usage `import { of } from 'rxjs'; return of(res);` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths & 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Actually I have imports messed up. In latest version of RxJS we can import it like that:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: After my 192nd double-take, I noticed that in my code I was importing from **`operator/`** - `rxjs/add/operator/of` - instead of `observable/`. D'oh.

Comment: I found I don't need to use this statement in one of angular  projects. But in the other one, I have to import it. I don't understand the differences. Do you know the reasons?

Comment: Angular version, perhaps?!  I didn't have to do this for 4.3.2 but I did for 5.0.0.

Comment: @Draghon: Exactly the same with me. I didn't have to do it for 4.4, I do now for 5.2. Even more weird, I only have to include it in one file and all other .ts-files simply pick it up and are good to go.

Comment: What if I get  Cannot find module "rxjs/add/observable/of" ?

Answer (score 220):

If anybody is having this problem while using Angular >= 6 and rxjs version 6 or greater, see the answers here:
[Could not use Observable.of in RxJs 6 and Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220854/could-not-use-observable-of-in-rxjs-6-and-angular-6)

In short, you need to import it like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

And then instead of calling

```
Observable.of(res);
```

just use

```
of(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! Figuring out imports in Rx is always such a huge source of frustration for me because of the api volatility.

Comment: Finally.  Spent an hour going through different permutations until this answer finally solved this issue.  Why did they make this so hard?

Answer (score 44):

Although it sounds absolutely strange, with me it mattered to capitalize the 'O' in the import path of `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable`. The error message with `observable_1.Observable.of is not a function` stays present if I import the Observable from `rxjs/observable`. Strange but I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 30):

My silly mistake was that I forgot to add `/add` when requiring the observable.

**Was:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Which visually looks OK becasue `rxjs/observable/of` file, in fact, exists.

**Should be:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: as @Shaun_grady pointed out, somehow this doesnt work. I did go with his proposal

Answer (score 22):

Patching wasn't working for me, for whatever reason, so I had to resort to this method:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'

// ...

return of(res)
```

Comment: This isn't a work around, this is the syntax for  Angular >= 6.0.0. import { of } from 'rxjs' was fine for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067580/property-of-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-observable

Answer (score 18):

Just to add,

if you're using many of them then you can import all using

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

as mentioned by @Thierry Templier. But I think If you are using limited operator then you should import individual operator like

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

as mentioned by @uksz.

Because 'rxjs/Rx' will import all the Rx components which definitely cost performance.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: I found I don't need to use this statement in one of angular  projects. But in the other one, I have to import it. I don't understand the differences. Do you know the reasons?

Answer (score 16):

You could also import all operators this way:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: I would not recommend importing this way, as this is a quite big library and      "of" is a very small part of it.

Comment: @methgaard  `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` doesn't work. Only `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` works. The version is 5.4.2

Comment: @methgaard I'm sorry. I made a mistake. The fact is I got `Observable_1.Observable.of(...).delay(...).timeout is not a function`. I didn't use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'`

Comment: It also increases the bundle size

Answer (score 5):

I am using Angular 5.2 and RxJS 5.5.6

This code did **not** work:

```
     import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs/Observable';

     getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
        return of(Hero[]) HEROES;

      }
```

Below code worked:

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

     getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> 
     {
          return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
              observer.next(HEROES);
              observer.complete();
          });

      }
```

Calling method:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
```

I think they might moved/changed of() functionality in RxJS 5.5.2

Answer (score 4):

This should work properly just try it.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// "rxjs": "^5.5.10"
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

.... 
return of(res)
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Would you please explain what you're trying to suggest?

Comment: Hi there, we should only import the operator that we need, not the whole "Observable" because of performance issue. In the the new version (^5.5.10) the right way to import "of" operator is: import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of' ... It works for my case. I will edit my resolution. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 4):

**Upgraded from Angular 5 / Rxjs 5 to Angular 6 / Rxjs 6?**

You must change your imports and your instantiation. [Check out Damien's blog post](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/rxjs-5-5-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-e825129c2068)

**Tl;dr:**

```
import { Observable, fromEvent, of } from 'rxjs';

const yourResult = Observable
    .create(of(yourObservable))
    .startWith(null)
    .map(x => x.someStringProperty.toLowerCase());

//subscribe to keyup event on input element
Observable
    .create(fromEvent(yourInputElement, 'keyup'))
    .debounceTime(5000)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((event) => {
        yourEventHandler(event);
    });
```

Comment: Using 6.0, attempting to subscribe to Observable.create(of(val)) resulted in "this._subscribe is not a function".  Instead, I successfully created an observable by just calling "of(val)".

Answer (score 3):

**RxJS 6**

When upgrading to version 6 of the `RxJS` library and not using the `rxjs-compat` package the following code

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';   
  // ...
  return Observable.of(res);
```

has to be changed into

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
  // ...
  return of(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

For me (Angular 5 & RxJS 5) the autocomplete import suggested:

```
import { Observable } from '../../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';
```

while to should be (with all static operators `from`, `of`, e.c.t working fine:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today. I'm using systemjs to load the dependencies.

I was loading the Rxjs like this:

```
...
    paths: {
        "rxjs/*": "node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.min.js"
    },
...
```

Instead of use paths use this:

```
var map = {
...
'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
...
}

var packages = {
...
'rxjs': { main: 'bundles/Rx.umd.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
...
}
```

This little change in the way systemjs loads the library fixed my problem.

Comment: The question applies to Angular 2. [It doesn't perform well with RxJS UMD module](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359).

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 5+ :

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`should work. The observer package should match the import as well `import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';` if you're using observers that is

`import {<something>} from 'rxjs';` does a huge import so it's better to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

shows a requirement of rxjs-compat

```
require("rxjs-compat/add/observable/of");
```

I did not have this installed. Installed by

```
npm install rxjs-compat --save-dev
```

and rerunning fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In `rxjs` v6, `of` operator should be imported as `import { of } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow even Webstorm made it like this `import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';`
and everything started to work