# observable.of cannot be found in version 6.0.0-tactical-rc.1

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im building service that should temporarily return Observable of some array before the server API will constructed. Before upgrading to angular and other packages to 6.0.0-rc.3 version i used following syntax:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


@Injectable()
export class GeocodesService {
   getPositions():Observable<any>{     
        return Observable.of({ })
   }
}
```

At 6.0.0-rc.3, this syntax looks deprecated
Trying to import it following way (using latest angular):

```
 import 'rxjs/observable/of'
```

But Getting error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/of'
```

How import of "of" can be done with latest rxjs?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using RxJS 5.5 it's `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'. In RxJS 5.6 you should use `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable.of is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568388/observable-of-is-not-a-function)

Comment: tryed this way already - getting: node_modules/rxjs/observable/of"' has no exported member 'of'

Comment: yes, the result is "Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/of'"

Answer (score 9):

Finally found the solution [here](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter)

This guy (Tomas Trajan), uses following syntax:

```
import { Observable , of} from 'rxjs'
```

and after you can use:

```
 getWidgets() {
    return of([]);
 }
```

Comment: I kept trying to
`Observable.of` 
you're the first to explain the fix which is just to use `of`
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the patching imports with RxJS version 6, you will also need to install `rxjs-compat`.

It's a separate package that adds backwards compatibility (with RxJS version 5) to RxJS version 6:

```
npm install rxjs-compat@6.0.0-tactical-rc.1
```

With `rxjs-compat` installed, your patching imports should work just fine.

For more information, see the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: Discoverability seems like a major issue.

Comment: I believe there is a migration guide that's being prepared.

Comment: That is good but plenty of people will not realize that they need to migrate at all, especially if they get upgraded transitively. I think the better approach would have been to leave it alone.

Comment: patching imports - does this mean the "tactical" have no more "of" operator?

Comment: Patching imports are those like `import "rxjs/add/..."`. They've been removed in v6. The `rxjs-compat` package adds them back. Patching imports have numerous problems; problems explicit factory imports and [pipeable operators do not have](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). Personally, I'm glad they are gone.

Comment: +1 glad they are gone. Upgrading from 5.x.x to 6.0.0 means that there are breaking changes to be aware of, so people doing this transition should handle this carefully eg reading changelogs, release details or migration guides.

Comment: The [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) has just been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your imports and your instantiation. [Check out Damien's blog post](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/rxjs-5-5-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-e825129c2068)

**Tl;dr:**

```
import { Observable, fromEvent, of } from 'rxjs';

const yourResult = Observable
    .create(of(yourObservable))
    .startWith(null)
    .map(x => x.someStringProperty.toLowerCase());

//subscribe to keyup event on input element
Observable
    .create(fromEvent(yourInputElement, 'keyup'))
    .debounceTime(5000)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((event) => {
        yourEventHandler(event);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using :

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
```

**throw error in Angular v6 or 6+**

use like this:

```
import {of as useOf } from 'rxjs';
```

...............
....
..............

```
getBooks():Observable<Book[]>{
return useOf(this.BOOKS);
```

}

**Error Solved!!!**