# Angular - rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.of is not a function

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AppSettings } from "./appsettings";
@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {
    getSettings(): Observable<AppSettings> {
        let settings = new AppSettings();
        return Observable.of<AppSettings>(settings);
    }
}
```

above is my angular5 code but i'm facing issue . please see the console error image .

[image: if your have any idea about this issue please share with me.]

Comment: which version of `rxjs` are you using?

Comment: how can i check version of rxjs?

Comment: in your `package.json` you will find a line like this: `"rxjs": "5.5.6"` under section `dependencies`

Comment: rxjs version is {"rxjs": "^6.3.3"}

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568388/observable-of-is-not-a-function
Anyway you could try to do something like `return of<AppSettings>(settings)` or  `return of(settings as AppSettings)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because from version 6 onwards, the package structure of rxjs has changed. The below code works for Angular 6:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable , of} from 'rxjs';
import { AppSettings } from "./appsettings";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppSettingsService {
    getSettings(): Observable<AppSettings> {
        let settings = new AppSettings();
        return of<AppSettings>(settings);
    }
}
```