# RxJS equivalent of Promise.resolve()

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

What is the equivalent of `Promise.resolve()` (resolving without any value is important) ?

There is a similar question here : [rxjs alternative to doing a Promise.resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616540/rxjs-alternative-to-doing-a-promise-resolve).

The given solution (`Observable.of(data)`) works well if we provide any data but this doesn't work if we don't provide a value which make sense to me as there is no value, so `.subscribe()` is not fired.

In an Angular2 service of an ionic2 app, I'm trying to migrate a Promise based service to Observables. If device is offline, I need to skip some steps of a sequence. With promises, I was throwing an Error and catching it later in the sequence :

```
return this.connectivityService.isOnline()
  .flatMap((isOnline: boolean) => {
    if (isOnline) {
      return Promise.resolve(); // work as expected, subscribe() is called
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(new OfflineError('The device is offline.'));
    }
  })
  .do(() => console.log('Do things here'));
```

The following code doesn't:

```
return this.connectivityService.isOnline()
  .flatMap((isOnline: boolean) => {
    if (isOnline) {
      return Observable.of(); // subscribe() is not called
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(new OfflineError('The device is offline.'));
    }
  })
  .do(() => console.log('Do things here'));
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with observables ? Feel free to tell me if I have a bad usage of observables, this is something new for me.

Comment: try to return dummy data: `return Observable.of(1);`

Comment: @TiepPhan Returning `Observable.of(1)` will work but imho, this is more a hack than a viable solution.

Comment: `Observable.of(undefined)` is the exact equivalent.

Comment: yep, we still using some hack in js, this is not too bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in a direct manner:

The equivalent of `Promise.resolve()` would be `Observable.of(undefined)` - but usually you can avoid such workarounds.

Did you simplify your code? Because in your case you don't actually have to use a `flatMap` here, you could also simply throw an error directly:

```
return this.connectivityService.isOnline()
  .do((isOnline: boolean) => {
    if (!isOnline) {
      throw new OfflineError('The device is offline.');
    }
  })
  .do(() => console.log('Do things here'));
```

---

```js
const isOnline$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(false); // some online-check-service-mock

isOnline$
  .do(isOnline => {
    if (!isOnline) {
      throw new Error("You are offline!");  
    }
  })
  .do(() => console.log('Do things here'))
  .subscribe(
    console.log,
    error => console.error("Oops! ", error.message),
    console.info
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes the code snippet is simplified, When online, I fetch data from a remote API and I update my local database, I download some files so they can be available offline etc. Then, I fetch data from my local database to render it (more or less), following the concept of "offline first" apps.

Comment: `Observable.of(undefined)` is working as expected. I was looking for a specific operator but i was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, but you could still to the fetching of stuff when online in an appended `flatMap` - there really should not be the need of the `Observable.of`-workaround here.

Comment: I'm learning observables so you are probably right, I will investigate this. Thank you!